# PostgreSQL pgAdmin III SSL connection to AWS RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, ssl, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to RDS running on AWS (Amazon Web Services) **using SSL**. I saw limited info in PosgreSQL pgAdmin III docs about fields on SSL tab.

> RDS instances are setup to accept SSL connections by default.

I've downloaded the public key from Amazon and converted it from a `.pem` to a `.crt` file using openSSL. On the SSL tab in pgAdmin III I entered path to converted key file "Server Root Certificate File" field.

I can connect to instance without issue *but there is no indication that the data is being transferred over SSL*. **AWS does not set their RDS instances to use SSL exclusivly** so I may be connected without using SSL and not know it.

Does pgAdmin III show any indication when it's connected using SSL *(like a lock icon)*? 
Can anyone provide additional info that describes the fields (SSL dropdown, Client Cert File, Client Key) on the SSL tab in pgAdmin III?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have not used SSL with PGAdmin on AWS, but I have on a server, and I can tell you that you know when you are connected to a server via PGAdmin, I'm not sure how there is ambiguity there, can you see the databases, tables?

The quoted post below might help you with connecting to a server via SSL.

> On the client, we need three files. For Windows, these files must be
>   in %appdata%\postgresql\ directory. For Linux ~/.postgresql/
>   directory. root.crt (trusted root certificate) postgresql.crt (client
>   certificate) postgresql.key (private key)
>
> Generate the the needed files on the server machine, and then copy
>   them to the client. We'll generate the needed files in the /tmp/
>   directory.
>
> First create the private key postgresql.key for the client machine,
>   and remove the passphrase.
>
> ```
> openssl genrsa -des3 -out /tmp/postgresql.key 1024
>
> openssl rsa -in /tmp/postgresql.key -out /tmp/postgresql.key
> ```
>
> Then create the certificate postgresql.crt. It must be signed by our
>   trusted root (which is using the private key file on the server
>   machine). Also, the certificate common name (CN) must be set to the
>   database user name we'll connect as.
>
> ```
> openssl req -new -key /tmp/postgresql.key -out /tmp/postgresql.csr -subj '/C=CA/ST=British Columbia/L=Comox/O=TheBrain.ca/CN=www-data'
>
> openssl x509 -req -in /tmp/postgresql.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey server.key -out /tmp/postgresql.crt -CAcreateserial
> ```
>
> Copy the three files we created from the server /tmp/ directory to the
>   client machine.
>
> Copy the trusted root certificate root.crt from the server machine to
>   the client machine (for Windows pgadmin %appdata%\postgresql\ or for
>   Linux pgadmin ~/.postgresql/). Change the file permission of
>   postgresql.key to restrict access to just you (probably not needed on
>   Windows as the restricted access is already inherited). Remove the
>   files from the server /tmp/ directory.

From: http://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates

Answer (score -2):

First, login as your postgresql admin user then run the following to install sslinfo on RDS:

```
create extension sslinfo;
```

To verify if you're connected via ssl simply run the following query in your session:

```
select ssl_is_used();
```

If it returns true (t), then you're connected via SSL.